# Creating 0-100 percent object in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am currently creating a GUI(Graphical User Interface) for my Matlab programs and in one of the programs, one of the arguments is a percentage from a whole.
What I want to do is, create some form of object that presents numbers from 0-100 and the user increases the number by 1 or decrease by -1 with every press of the arrow buttons.
Is there such an object that will help me do that? And how do I create it?

Comment: Do you mean object as in Object-Oriented Programming or object as a graphical element of the figure? This can be easily done with a single `WindowKeyPressFcn`, without resorting to matlab OOP.

Comment: isn't WindowKeyPressFcn purpose so that the user presses his keyboard and it happens on the GUI?

Comment: The user presses a keybord button and this function is evaluated. Isn't this what you need? See my answer. If this is not what you are looking for - please be more precise in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
function test_perc

figh = figure();
% create a text control that will display the 0 - 100 text
texth = uicontrol('Style', 'text', 'Units', 'normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], 'FontSize', 56, ...
    'String', '0');
% set a function that handles key presses (uses handle to the text object)
set(figh, 'WindowKeyPressFcn', @(hobj, ev) percfun(ev, texth));

function percfun(ev, texth)
% check if leftarrow or rightarrow has been 
% pressed and modify text accordingly 
if strcmp(ev.Key, 'leftarrow')
    val = max(0, str2num(get(texth, 'String')) - 1);
    set(texth, 'String', num2str(val));
elseif strcmp(ev.Key, 'rightarrow')
    val = min(100, str2num(get(texth, 'String')) + 1);
    set(texth, 'String', num2str(val));
end
```

The code above creates a `figure` and a `uicontrol` of style 'text'. The figure is then set to respond to keypresses (`WindowKeyPressFcn`) with a specific function (`percfun`) that responds to arrows by setting the text of the uicontrol. 
If you have any questions - ask, I will elucidate.